# Subrelationships not using previous conditions

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 4. I have the following models:

```
class User extends Eloquent  {

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('UserQuestion', 'user_id', 'user_id');
    }

}

class UserQuestion extends Eloquent  {

    protected $table = 'user_questions';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function subquestions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('UserSubquestion', 'question_id', 'id');
    }

}

class UserSubquestion extends Eloquent  {

    protected $table = 'user_subquestions';

    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('UserQuestion', 'question_id');
    }

    public function answers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('UserAnswer', 'subquestion_id', 'id');
    }

}

class UserAnswer extends Eloquent  {

    protected $table = 'user_answers';

    public function subquestion()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('UserSubquestion', 'subquestion_id');
    }

}
```

I have the following query:

```
$results = User::with(['questions' => function($query) {
        $query->where('status', '1');
        $query->where('category', 'medicine');
    }])
    ->with('questions.subquestions', 'questions.subquestions.answers')
    ->get();
```

However, the `where` conditions I'm applying to the `questions` relationship  aren't being applied to the joined tables (`subquestions` and `answers`).

How can I make the conditions apply to them as well?

Note: The values of `status` and `category` in the conditions are dynamic (i.e. won't always be `1` or `medicine`).

Comment: Do the models (UserQuestion, UserSubquestion and UserAnswer) all have the fields `status` and `category`?

Comment: No, only `questions` has those fields.

Comment: what do you want ? can you explain your output too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing your call like this instead:

```
$results = User::with(['questions' => function($query) {
        $query->where('status', '1');
        $query->where('category', 'medicine');
    },
    'questions.subquestions',
    'questions.subquestions.answers'
])->get();
```

Note, this time the method `with` is only called once.

Comment: Huh, that did it. Interesting. Thanks!